# in pure Javascript, how do I get all elements inside the body tag excluding a certain div and its children?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to find all the elements inside the body tag, but there is one element (div) that has a certain class type of "hidden" which I want to exclude it and its children from my array of elements.

here is my var that contains all the elements in the body:

```
allTagsInBody = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

and here is the div that I want to exclude from this list:

```
<div class="myHiddenElement"> 
    <button>Click here</button>
    <div> <button>Click here</button> </div>
    <button>Click here</button>
</div>
```

the problem is that I don't know how many elements there are inside that div and how far nested they are.

Comment: Please note that the children do not have the "myHiddenElement" class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you iterate through each element, you need to not only check if it has your hidden class but if any of its parent elements have the class. Thus you need to recursively check each element's parents. This can be very expensive depending on the number of elements on the page and how deeply nested they are, but here's how's it's done:

```
var arr = [];
var len;
var i;
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('body *');

function checkNode(node) {
    if (node.classList.contains('myHiddenElement')) {
        return true;        
    } else if (node.parentNode.nodeType === 1) {
        return checkNode(node.parentNode);
    }

    return false;
};

for (i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (checkNode(nodes[i])) {
        continue;
    } else {
        arr.push(nodes[i]);
    }
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/xzCfs/5/

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to do this with CSS selectors since the :not() selector only accepts simple selectors, not compound ones (e.g., :not(.myHiddenClass *)  <-- would be awesome if that worked).

Comment: I should note that these are the basics for what you are trying to achieve but there are several optimizations that could be made. For example, since all sibling elements have the same ancestors, you can mark a parent as already checked so that you do not keep recursively checking it and its own parents after you've already done it once.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll( '*:not(.myHiddenElement)' );
```

The `.querySelectorAll` along with `css2` *:not()* selector will do it.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem here that this solution is not taking into account that the children do not have the "myHiddenElement" class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
​​var elems = document.body.childNodes;
var filtered = Array();  //holds elements that doesn't have 'myHiddenElement' class

​for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++)
{
    if(elems[i].className != 'myHiddenElement')
      filtered.push(elems[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails you can always recursively traverse the DOM (it's what all the libraries do anyway):

Here's a generic DOM traverse function:

```
# Note: Even though this function accepts a callback it is synchronous:

function traverse (node, callback) {
    // The callback function must return true to continue processing
    // otherwise stop processing down this branch:
    if (callback(node)) {
        for (var i=0;i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            traverse(node.childNodes[i],callback);
        }
    }
}
```

So, to build up your collection:

```
var elements = [];
traverse(document,function(node){
    // We only care about element nodes, ignore comments, attributes etc:
    if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.className != "myHiddenElement") {
        elements.push(node);
        return true; // continue parsing this branch
    }
    return false; // ignore this branch and its children
});
```